# Is it possible to use 6GB of memory in my MacBook Pro 3,1?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

The specifications of my MacBook Pro say the maximum memory supported is 4GB using two 2GB DDR2 667MHz each.

However, some say that this model can support up to 6GB of memory, putting a 4GB Memory DDR3 1066MHz in one of the slot and 2GB (or 4GB, 6GB directing in this case memory).

The bus is 800MHz MacBook Pro. How should I install memory in the two memory slots to get the highest memory capacity and performance in my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. I own a MacBook Pro 3,1. I installed 6GB memory and have been using it like that for more than two years. **Note the specifications below.** You can call the tech support people at [Other World Computing](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/5300DDR2S6GP/) if you have any questions.

The RAM in my system is as follows:

- Bank 0: 2GB DDR2 SDRAM 667 MHz
- Bank 1: 4GB DDR2 SDRAM 667 MHz

Comment: Please note that the RAM that Wheat linked to is DDR2 667MHz, which is what you need. You won't be able to use DDR3 RAM because it won't physically fit into a DDR2 slot.

Comment: @joelseph, you are correct; I confirmed these details and posted results from System Information.

Answer (score 1):

Your Macbook Pro does support 6GB of RAM.

Apple states that it's 4GB, but **OWC** continuously check the max. supported RAM.

See this list [here](http://eshop.macsales.com/memory/maxram).

[image]